# Редирект c исключением через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, исключения, редирект

Нужна помощь с редиректом с домена на домен, но так, чтоб мониторинговый сервис, закрепленный за старым доменом оставался нетронутым

То бишь, чтоб редиректило на всё с olddomen.com на newdomen.com, но olddomen.com/monitor и всё, что за ним оставалось нетронутым. Подскажите, пожалуйста.